# Azure SDK and .NET 4.52

Tags: azure

I am not sure if I download Azure SDK 2.7 will it let me target .NET 4.5.2? Currently I have Azure SDK 4.5 and it does not let me publish when I have a worker role targeting 4.5.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Worker roles currently do not support .NET 4.5.2 without manual installation.

You can either set up VM access to install .NET 4.5.2 onto the worker role's underlying VM or look at usin a powershell script to install it when your application starts up.

See proof in [release notes for SDK 2.6](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/azure-sdk-dotnet-release-notes-2_6/) and instructions to how install .NET on cloud services [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-install-dotnet/).

Answer (score 0):

Azure SDK's currently only allow you to target 4.5.1 in PaaS services.  Azure SDK v2.5 and on is able to to target 4.5.2 but only if it is a VM instance

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn873976.aspx